# Add debounce to synchronous validator on FormControl?

Tags: angular, angular6

Is there a way to add a debounce to the synchronous parameter on FormControl?

The following is a sample snippet I have been using.

```javascript
this.userSignupForm = new FormGroup({
  email: new FormControl('', {
    validators: [Validators.email],
    asyncValidators: [UserValidator.uniqueEmail()],
  }),
});
```

A scenario I am expecting here is that user should see an error just after he has finished typing. We have added a debounce to the function passed in `asyncValidators` parameter but I am not sure how to proceed with the `validators` parameter.